# Redux-observable, dispatching two actions after fetch

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

I imagine this is a very common use case but can't find an example that clearly lays it out for me.

```
const openTriviaTokenEpic = (action$, store) =>
  action$
    .ofType(OT_GET_TOKEN)
    .mergeMap(action =>
      Observable.from(fetch(OPEN_TRIVIA_API + "api_token.php?command=request"))
        .flatMap(res => Observable.from(res.json()))
        .map(fetchRes => {
          console.log("fetch sub token", fetchRes);
          let actions = [getOpenTriviaTokenSuccess(fetchRes.token), getOpenTriviaQuestions()];
          return Observable.from(actions);
        })
    )
    .catch(result => Observable.of(getOpenTriviaTokenFailure({ message: "Unable to retrieve token for Trivia." })));
```

I see my fetch is happening, then I want to dispatch two actions:

- fetch token success
- use token to get data

I'm returning an Observable on those two actions but I get the following error in my console:

> Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.
>       at Object.performAction

And my action is this:

```
export const getOpenTriviaTokenSuccess = payload => {
  console.log("payload", payload);
  return {
    type: OT_GET_TOKEN_SUCCESS,
    payload: payload
  };
};
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

If you're returning an observable, you'll need to use `flatMap` instead of `map`:

```js
.flatMap(fetchRes => {
  console.log("fetch sub token", fetchRes);
  let actions = [getOpenTriviaTokenSuccess(fetchRes.token), getOpenTriviaQuestions()];
  return Observable.from(actions);
})
```